# Unseen MYSQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im receiving the following error with my MySQL statement -

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':username' at line 1'

Now here is a section of my code including the statement -

```
    $dbh = pdo_users();

    $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $info = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This is my connection -

```
function pdo_users()
{
try
{                                                                                         
    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'username', 'password');
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    header('Location: error.php');
}

return $connect;
```

}

Comment: You're using `$stmt = $dbh->query` but using `$connect` as your PDO variable connection. Pretty sure that's it. `$stmt = $connect->query`

Comment: Just added the line the rules that out

Comment: I'm baffled. I'll let somebody else take over from here.

Comment: Woahhhh... ok I know now. `$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");` you need to prepare. `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");`

Comment: At what line does php fail exactly ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- you won, was going to write that

Comment: @Andre Darnest thing, was staring me in the face all this time lol

Comment: Give the mans answer a tick, @AshleyW :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
```

You need to [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) it, not [query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) it.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
```